# I am not able to install pyaudio in my machine , having python version 3.7 after intalling the microsoft visual c++ 14.0.?

Tags: python, installation, pyaudio

i have installed the visual studio 2019 build tool , c++. Still  i am having the problem in my cmd prompt, shown below.

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\nisith saha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NISITH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p2pi0hy3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NISITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7qtci57w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DMS_WIN64=1 "-Ic:\users\nisith saha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include" "-Ic:\users\nisith saha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\nisith saha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.21.27702\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\nisith saha\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NISITH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p2pi0hy3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NISITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-7qtci57w\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NISITH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p2pi0hy3\pyaudio\
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need the Portaudio development headers and libraries installed.

Instead of doing that, I think you'll find it easier to get the proper precompiled wheel for Py3.7 from Christoph Gohlke's site over here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

The wheel you'll want should be `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`. I won't hotlink to it since it's expressly discouraged by Gohlke.